# How can I show a loading gui in javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx

This function loads my "Please wait..." gui:

```
public void showLoading(Stage ownerStage){
try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("/de/ern/loading/Loading.fxml"));
        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        LoadingController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setLoadingText("Please wait...");
        waitStage = new Stage();
        waitStage.setTitle("Please wait");
        waitStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("logo.png")));//setzt das Icon
        waitStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        waitStage.initOwner(ownerStage);
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        waitStage.setScene(scene);
        waitStage.show();   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How do I have to call it, because when I call it directly it's always empty. Only the pane with title is shown. I found a lot of code snippets für Swing but not for javafx.

EDIT:

I call it from the Controller of the main gui like this:

```
mainApp.showLoading(primaryStage);
AllgemeinTab liveWerte = new AllgemeinTab(this);
liveWerte.setName(getAllgTabName());
liveWerte.setBeschreibungDe(getAllgTabBeschreibungDe());
```

and after that, there follows a large database transaction.

This is my FXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="292.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="de.ernst.loading.LoadingController">
<children>
<ImageView fx:id="imgLoading" fitHeight="25.0" fitWidth="25.0" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="19.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0">
     <image>
        <Image url="@loading.gif" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <Text layoutX="54.0" layoutY="25.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Status:" AnchorPane.topAnchor="17.0">
     <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
     </font></Text>
  <Text fx:id="txtLoadingDescription" layoutX="54.0" layoutY="24.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Beschreibung..." wrappingWidth="230.44140625" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Create and post a [MCVE]. There appears to be nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Can you paste your fxml file?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the [Preloader](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Preloader.html) 
([Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm)). A Preloader is a really small application with a Stage that gets loaded before your application gets loaded and you can send some informations to the preloader to display progress.

That may gives you more options

Answer (score 1):

You can show a "loading GUI' by displaying a [ProgressIndicator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html)

So show the ProgressIndicator, then you need to do your Backgroundwork in a new Thread, and then you replace your ProgressIndicator with the new Content.

```
final ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator();
progress.setMaxSize(50, 50);
rootPane.setCenter(progress);

new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() { 
                   rootPane.setCenter(new Label("done"));
            }
        });  
    }
}).start();
```